# Redirect when intercept-url is not authorized in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been working on Spring security since a year. Today I faced a minor problem regarding Authorization in Spring Security

For intercept url I have configured my spring-security.xml like this

```
<intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/groups" access="hasRole('VIEW_GROUPS')" />

<intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('VIEW_ADMIN')" />
```

This might happen that a user has no role to see /groups page so in that case how can I make sure that user is automatically redirected to /admin page?

I know answer would be simple but I got stuck here.

Comment: Is the user that "has no role to see /groups page" already authenticatd?

Comment: Yes that user is being authenticated using custom authentication provider.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the redirect in the access denied handler.

Usually you will have something like this in your configuration:

```
<http ..... >
  ...
  <intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/groups" access="hasRole('VIEW_GROUPS')" />
  <intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('VIEW_ADMIN')" />
  ...
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/access-denied" />
</http>
```

URL /access-denied usually displays the access denied page. You could register a controller to that URL and then you could check in the controller if user has role "VIEW_ADMIN" and redirect him there. If you need to know which URL user attempted to visit, it should be available in HttpServletRequest object.

EDIT: solution via interceptor:

You could create a Spring MVC interceptor. Extend HandlerInterceptorAdapter and in the preHandle method check if user is authenticated and check the roles and do a redirect.

```
class MyRoleBasedRedirectorInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
       //do the authentication/role/URL checks
       ...
       if (needsAdminRedirect) {
           response.sendRedirect("admin");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

}
```

And in the config:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.MyRoleBasedRedirectorInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

If you dislike original controller solution you can also implement your own AccessDeniedHandler implementation and to the checks there. You would plug in your implementation with

```
<access-denied-handler ref="com.example.MyAccessDeniedHandler" />
```

I would still opt for Controller / AccessDeniedHandler solution since, if I understood correctly, redirect happens only when a user is not authorized to visit "groups" page.

Comment: Can we use some filter for this purpose? In which we check if user has no authorization on some intercept url then redirect to other page.

Comment: Yes you can. I edited answer to include interceptor solution. You could do it in servlet Filter too in almost identical way.